# Kubernetes 1.18 on EKS StartupProbe with old ServiceAccountName

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I've got a deployment which worked just fine on K8S 1.17 on EKS. After upgrading K8S to 1.18, I tried to use `startupProbe` feature with a simple deployment. Everything works as expected. But when I tried to add the `startupProbe` to my production deployment, it didn't work. The cluster simply drops the `startupProbe` entry when creating pods (the `startupProbe` entry exists in deployment object definition on the cluster though). Interestingly when I change the `serviceAccountName` entry to `default` (instead of my application service account) in the deployment manifest, everything works as expected.
So the question now is, why existing service accounts can't have startup probes?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you use annotation `eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn` on the ServiceAccount? If yes, then there is open [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/95604) about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community member answer. Feel free to expand.

### Issue

> startupProbe is not applied to Pod if serviceAccountName is set
>
> When adding serviceAccountName and startupProbeto the pod template in my deployment, the resulting pods will not have a startup probe.

There is [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/95604) about that.

### Solution

This issue is being addressed [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook/issues/84), currently it is still open and there is no specific answer for this.

As mentioned by @mcristina422

> I think this is due to the old version of k8s.io/api being used in the webhook. The API for the startup probe was added more recently. Updating the k8s packages should fix this